# Android draw a rectangle to navigation drawer menu item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have to create a navigation drawer with a custom menu item.
I know I can create a ListView with custom item layout or use third-party libs etc., but I feel that would be an overkill for this little modification, because the 'default' working method is almost perfect for me.

I have to draw a little rectangle with different color to every menu item.
Can I achieve this with default components somehow?

[image]

Comment: You want to have squares with different colors instead of the icons? Not sure I understood correctly.

Comment: Yes, you absolutely understood me. But the square's position is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've successfully solved the problem by using Mike Penz's [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library with custom drawer item and custom item layout.